# How to store Vue.prototype.$something in a separate file?

Tags: vue.js, webpack

how can I declare Vue.prototype.$myVariable in an imported file to don't litter up main.js?

Answer (score 1):

You could create a [plugin](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/plugins.html) that sets the variable(s):

#### Vue 2

```js
// myPlugin.js
export default {
  install(Vue) {
    Vue.prototype.$myVariable = 'foo'
  }
}

// main.js
import Vue from 'vue'
import MyPlugin from './myPlugin'

Vue.use(MyPlugin)

new Vue({
  mounted() {
    console.log(this.$myVariable)
  }
}).$mount('#app')
```

#### Vue 3

```js
// myPlugin.js
export default {
  install(app) {
    app.config.globalProperties.$myVariable = 'foo'
  }
}

// main.js
import { createApp } from 'vue'
import MyPlugin from './myPlugin'

createApp({
  mounted() {
    console.log(this.$myVariable)
  }
})
.use(MyPlugin)
.mount('#app')
```